# Event Listeners not working for Ustream API

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

I've been trying to add a Ustream live channel feed on my web page. I've created a setup on
[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/phoenix4rmhell/SmjrT/)

```
viewer.addListener('finished', channelFinished);
viewer.addListener('live', channelLive);
viewer.addListener('offline', channelOffline);
```

I've added these listeners and none of them is working.
I get this error in the console

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'call' of undefined** on Chrome

The error is basically because of an undefined variable.

I've checked other functions like

```
viewer.callMethod('seek', 175);
viewer.getPropoerty('duration' callback_function);
```

and these methods are working fine

can someone help me out with this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please define your listeners before add to a viewer.
Like this:

```
    var channelLive = function(){
        alert("Channel is live");
    }
    var viewer = UstreamEmbed('video');
    viewer.callMethod('load', 'channel', 1524);
    viewer.addListener('live', channelLive);
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out with this @Ferenc Boldog. 
Thanks MackieeE

Comment: <script src="http://static.ustream.tv/js/libs/ustream-embedapi.min.js"></script> the js is no more located. Where can I find the new one?

Comment: Finally located in: https://github.com/ustream/embedapi/tree/master/src